# Graph database that supports efficient sorting and/or range retrieval

Tags: database, graph, graph-databases

Using Twitter's data model as an example:

User A follows N other users, each of whom posted N different posts. Posts are timestamped.

Is there a data store or graph database that supports efficiently reading the latest N posts from users that User A is following?

It seems best that posts are stored in sort order (like a Cassandra ColumnFamily or a Redis ZSET).

Also, the ability to shard the data across different machines is critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/), it should fit your needs perfectly. One recommendation though, use its [REST interface](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Getting_Started_With_Neo4j_Server) since it gives you the freedom to chose your weapon uhm programming language and abstracts a lot of the complexity of working with the Java bindings directly

Comment: Thanks -- I was looking at neo4j but didn't find a way to store relationships in sorted order across the same type, (e.g., LIKES) (which is really what I think I need to do). Is there some kung-fu in the indexing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

An option for you might be ... RDF Databases (AKA triple stores/quad stores) and try [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) to query graphs and retrieve subgraphs from your data. See also [SPARQL by example](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/2008/09/sparql-by-example/).

One that scales up to billions of triples or quads is [4store](http://4store.org/), it is written in C and allows data sharding across segments, It makes the most of commodity clusters or multi-core architectures. There are a wide range of client libraries to interact with it from Java, perl, Python, ...

Comment: Thanks, 4store looks really interesting.

Comment: No problem. If help needed ... http://groups.google.com/group/4store-support or on their #4store IRC channel on freenode. People tend to be very helpful and respond very quickly.